# How can i run a socket.io server continuously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, putty, vps

i'm trying to code a whiteboard app. AND i'm using socket.io for real time comm.. To do that, i'm logging in my VPS via putty and I'm starting the server like "node server.js", but when I log off from VPS (closing putty) normally the server shuts down. So, how can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your server console hit this command firstly this will install forever module

```
$ sudo npm install forever -g
```

use sudo according to your permission in your server

then hit this command in your server console

```
$ sudo forever start server.js
```

Comment: start or node ? i need "node" command for run the .js with node.js. (Thx for answer :) )

Comment: i did exactly same thing but; sudo: forever: command not found

Comment: is npm installed in your server

Comment: Delete the all the existing forever modules.

$ sudo rm -R /usr/lib/node_modules/forever
$ sudo rm -R /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever
Install the forever again.

$ sudo npm install forever -g

Comment: it's going right i think, but it's not work, now i have this msg;

sudo forever start server.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server.js

Comment: and how can i stop this server :)

Comment: just replace **start** to **stop** and if want to restart use **restart** keywork

Comment: thank you very very mush by the way :) it's working now (i restart it)

Comment: If the service needs to be running after a server restart, you can take a look at upstart or system V init scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use tmux so that the terminal doesnt dies when you logout of your VPS.

For ubuntu, `apt-get install byobu`
and in the byobu terminal use `node server.js`
Then you can exit the VPS without killing the terminal process.

Not recommended for production use.